# datetime.datetime + timedelta(days=5) is returning None

Tags: python, date, datetime, nonetype, timedelta

```
startdate = dt.strptime('13/12/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
enddate = dt.strptime('4/12/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
interval = 5
print('startdate', startdate)
print('enddate', enddate)

loop_startdate = startdate
loop_endate = None

for _ in range((diff//interval) + 1):
    print(_, loop_startdate)
    loop_enddate = loop_startdate + timedelta(days=interval)
    print('loop_enddate', loop_endate)
    if loop_enddate > enddate:
        loop_enddate = enddate
    loop_startdate = loop_endate
```

`startdate` and `enddate` are `datetime.datetime` instances. I have printed out 'startdate' and `enddate` and the results are given below.

```
startdate 2020-12-04 00:00:00
enddate 2020-12-13 00:00:00
0 2020-12-04 00:00:00
loop_enddate None
1 None
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "pythonfilepathhere", line 81, in <module>
    loop_enddate = loop_startdate + timedelta(days=interval)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I have double checked to make sure that `startdate` and `endate` are in `datetime.datetime` type. I actucally need it as date and not as datetime though. I tried using `loop_startdate.date() + timedelta()` also, but it is also returning None.

I don't understand why `datetime.datetime + timedelta()` is returning None. My Python version is `3.6.5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a small typo.

Change `print('loop_enddate', loop_endate)` to `print('loop_enddate', loop_enddate)`.

Also, change `loop_startdate = loop_endate` to `loop_startdate = loop_enddate`.

Comment: @Jihjohn Did it fix the problem?

Comment: Hey Josh. It did fix the problem. I can't digest that I just raised a SO question for a typo. I was debugging and writing few files together and didn't pay much attention. Thank you